# Return custom error message in ASP.NET Core Web Api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I am writing a webapi in `ASP.NET CORE 1.1`. I am trying to figure out how to return error message with not acceptable status code `406`.

Here is the method I have written in one of the Api controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostStoreCoolerData([FromBody] StoreCoolerData storeCoolerData)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        _context.StoreCoolerData.Add(storeCoolerData);
        var addResponse = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        if (addResponse > 0)
        {
            var getItemInfo = _context.StoreCoolerData.Include(c => c.CoolerBrand)
                                                      .Include(c => c.CoolerType)
                                                      .Include(c => c.DrinkType)
                                                      .Where(i => i.Id == storeCoolerData.Id);

            return CreatedAtAction("GetStoreCoolerData", new { getItemInfo });
        }
        return StatusCode(406, "There was a problem saving record in the database. Please try again.");
    }
```

As you can see I have `return StatusCode(406, "There was a problem saving record in the database. Please try again.");` at the end of my code. When I run the code and try to get response back with custom error, I am not getting custom error message rather I am getting Not Acceptable message.

Not sure if this is the right way to do it. Is there any other way I can include custom error message that is not 200 > or < 400?

Any help is really appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**

[image]

Thanks,

Ray

Comment: Ray your code is working for me. both the 406 and the error message are returned. maybe your browser is omitting the body when its a 406?  `rather I am getting Not Acceptable message.`  <-- what message is that?

Comment: @wal - ah.. I see it now. I was looking at `statusText` instead of `responseText`. As show in the image above in `UPDATE 1`. :)